# Googlemaps return object from initialize function

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a list of infowindows lets say numbered 1 to 5.
and they have a form to get directions. When I draw the route the infowindow should colapse. Everything works, I just want the infowindow object available outside the function

infowindow.close() works fine if its in initialize, however the function calcRoute() is outside of the initialize function. I'm trying to return the infowindow from the function but not sure where I am going wrong
here is the jest of what I'm doing

```
function initialize() {
........
var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: iwindow('marker3','st pete','27.81884967015435','-82.65828121138918','727-822','4011 mlk','Fl','33703','201'),
maxWidth: 300
});
.........
return infowindow3;
}

// I have tried alerting every combination of this, window and even the function name

alert(this.window.infowindow3);

// if it would alert ObjectObject I would have it.
```

I know I'm close and hopefully someone familiar with the maps can shed some light.
A big thank you in advance. (I have spent days trying to get this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a stupid question, but are you saving the return value of initialize?  Of course you are not showing your whole code, but that's not clear from what is there.  Something like this:

```
var infowindow3 = initialize();
alert(infowindow3);
```

Of course, the typical way to call initialize is via the load event, so you wouldn't be able to get the return value that way.  So you would set up a (in your example) global variable, and that set that global variable inside of initialize (and not returning anything).

Update:

Ok, after looking through the page you linked to (in your comment) I see that you are calling the `alert(infowindow3);` before `infowindow3` gets defined.  You can also see that in the page itself, the alert pops up with "undefined" and the page isn't loaded yet - you can't see any map and consequently `initialize()` hasn't run yet.  Bear in mind that during a page load, any script outside of a function (or a function's code if the function call is in that "open space") will get executed the moment the browser reads it.  This alert is an example of that.  You need to put that alert (or any code that uses this variable) in a function that does not get called until it is defined by `initialize()`.  Examples of this are functions that get called with `onclick`. In fact, `initialize` itself is an example of that (it gets called with `onload`).

Comment: I'm brand new to googlemaps and pretty much JavaScript. I'm a hard core php person.
    var infowindow3 = initialize();

Do I do that after new google.maps.InfoWindow?
If I do alert(infowindow3); within the initialize function, I get ObjectObject as expected.

Comment: I'm brand new to googlemaps and pretty much JavaScript. I'm a hard core php person.
    var infowindow3 = initialize();

Do I do that after new google.maps.InfoWindow is called?
If I do alert(infowindow3); within the initialize function, I get ObjectObject as expected.

problem is my  calculate route function is outside of initialize, this is where I (think) I want to collapse the infowindow.

function calculateRoute(){
window.infowindow3.close();
}

Comment: Reading your answer, my understanding of a global var in a function is not to use var before the variable.

When I try to do infowindow 3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ .....
It breaks the script.

Should I be doing var infowindow3; before the function call?

Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: `infowindow 3 = new...` will break the script because you have a space in the variable name.  Yes, as you say taking out the `var` will create a global variable.  Note that using global variables is not good practice because if everyone did this, variables would eventually conflict, but until you feel comfortable using more complex js structures go ahead and use them. And don't worry, we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: The space was a typo.

I'm sure that it is a global but not  sure how to get it, ie this.window.infowindow3.

The alert is on line 238.

Here is a link to what I have, its messy and hacked to death trying to get this to work [link](http://mx2.wifigator.com/z-gmap/z-debug.php)  I'm only concerned with infowindow3 for now. This is just a static version of a larger php/mysql driven map.

Comment: BTW, I really appreciate your time looking at this.

Comment: No problem!  If I answered your question, please accept it and also mark up (with the up arrow) all the answers that were in some way helpful.  No offense, Loren, but we mainly do this because we are addicted to the points - but don't ask, I can't understand that either. :) And thanks for asking a clear question and posting the link.  It makes it a lot easier to answer.

Comment: Hi 150, I have not given up. After trying many things I thought aha.

onload call the calculate route function by calcRoute('ini').

Then in the calcRoute function if (ini=='ini'){} else{calculate route}

My form has calcRoute('go') but

Comment: - continued: and there are alerts for load and calc route.

The alerts are all in the right place, the infowindow colapses (yay) but somehow the values for start and end get lost.

You definitely get the points and not sure if it closes this for further comment so I will wait a bit. OK now after typing all this I could call two functions with the get directions form, leave the calcRoute function as is and just onload the (new) close window function. Let me know your thoughts and the points are all yours.

Comment: I re-uploaded the debug script to the server, same place

Comment: I'm not sure about the start and end getting lost, but I think it has to do with the fact that the inputs are in the infowindow.  I'm guessing that google's code removes them instead of simply hiding them.  But I can't be sure, I haven't tested that before.  Maybe try putting the values in a hidden input?  Sorry I can't be more helpful there.  Have fun with it, though!